# Trying to multiply the first two numbers that results to a particular number, is there way i can do this without using nested loops?

Tags: javascript

Here is the full solution, please is there much better ways to go about this

the question is getting total number of squares in a box but in the inverse way, for example the normal question is 2,9 and the total number of available squares will be 26. but i was given the question in another way such that 26 will be given and im to find all the possible ways m and n can be arranged so the total number of squares will be the given question, which is 26

The code actually works but i need a faster way to do this.

```
const n = 26;
function count(m, n) {
    if (n < m) {
        const temp = n;
        n = m;
        m = temp;
    }
    return m * (m + 1) * (2 * m + 1) /
        6 + (n - m) * m * (m + 1) / 2;
}
const arr = [];

const len = n + 1;

for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if(i<len/2) {

    }
    for (let b = 1; b < len; b++) {
        if (i === 1) {
            arr.push(`${i} ${n}`);
            break;
        } else if (i === n) {
            arr.push(`${n} 1`);
            break;
        } else {


            const sum = count(i, b);
            if (sum == n) {
                arr.push(`${i} ${b}`);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


}
const arrLength = arr.length;
console.log(arrLength); //shows the length of the array

for (let g = 0; g < arrLength; g++) {
    console.log(arr[g]); // shows each ways it can be arranged to give 26

}
```

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: Based on your question, is the following example correct? if n == 4, then arr = [ '4 0', '3 1', '2 2', '1 3', '0 4']

Comment: Could you update your code to provide the `count` function? This question seems like it's better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: i have Updated the question